# How can I make jquery cycle show just a little bit of the next slide

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have a sliding (horizontal) gallery using jquery cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It works fine except one piece I want to add.  I want to have slide 1 visible, and slide 2 visible but just barely... You can see my current progress at http://www.4amnew.4thavenuemedia.com/client/bellevue-downtown-association/

The next button is just off the right side of the image.  I know I can put images into different div class="slide" but that doesn't achieve the look and feel.  I want an option like show 1.2 images...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the `display:none;` property that's added to all the slides. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that... it is a step in the right direction, but doesn't show any more images... I think because the width of the image is more than the width of the containing div

Comment: I think it's how the plug-in is calling them... They're absolutely positioned to the left I believe, and the non-active slide all have a lower `z-index` than the displayed slide. If you're just sliding images I'd suggest just using another slider or just coding up a quick one of your own.

Comment: I can try to make one, I'm not that well versed either but I can look around for one too.

Comment: Decided to go with jcarousel lite... Now I have to figure out how to create a slides index: 1 of 5 and captions that pull from the images alt tag and load into another div. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to achieve with CSS only, by changing where the "overflow: hidden" sits.

I wrote this up in to a Q&A here: [With jQuery Cycle 2 how do I show a part of the next and previous slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427318/with-jquery-cycle-2-how-do-i-show-a-part-of-the-next-and-previous-slides)